# How to @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; in file .html or .ts when using carousel

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, carousel

I want to import bootstrap carousel file only in one component `.ts` or `.html`, I don't want to use bootstrap in all project (I don't want to use it in `angular.json`). I want to import in only one `.ts` or `.html` component.

Can you share with me any idea how to do this, it's possible to do this?

Comment: carousel need bootstrap javascript and you need to import it in angular.json. Bootstrap doesn't have any export method

Answer (score 0):

You can copy past the css and javascript (optional) scripts in your .html or .ts files and it should work fine. Doc [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/).

If you have bootstrap downloaded in local, simply add the link to the css file and the script for javascript (works in html, not sure about TypeScript though) :

```
<link href="/path/to/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="path/to/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can only add css file like this. you can't add script

Comment: Edited my answer, does it help ?

Comment: No. This makes it wrong. my point is, if you add `script` tag in `.component.html`, angular compiler will remove it.

Comment: Oh ok, and I guess adding the `script` in your main file would apply bootstrap to the whole project